# rendering some dynamic blocks on page - express.js + jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Looking for a solution for a few days. Need help.

Source:
node.js + express.js + jade template engine

Problem:
Can't understand how I can render 1+ dynamic blocks on one page.

For example:

We have a page: News main page
Blocks on page: Latest news (list 20 itens), hot news (list 4 items), most viewed news (4 items), block with news categories (it can display current category on the page with page with card of one selected novelty, so it is dynamic block too), and block with some user auth data.
"block" i mean a widget as we can see on site, not a block of code.

What can I do in express? I can route special url to special function in routes.
So as I see, if a want to render all this blocks on the one page I have to call all functions rendering each block in only one function of route.

I mean it seems that I have to do something like this (sure in libs but doesn't matter here)

```
    app.get('/news', function(req, res){
      call_last_news(funcion(){
        call_hot_news(function(){
          call_get_user_info(function(){
            ...
            ...
            ...
            template.render.here();
            final_here();
          });
        });
      });
    });
```

This looks real but so unuseful and unsupportable code that .. That's bad.
I can see solution in calls from template engine to render some blocks on the page. But not just include because all blocks can use db or cookies, session data etc. all blocks are dynamic. But I have no idea how to create such engine using express.js + jade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm not certain I understood all of the problem but based on the pseudo code, it looks like the main concern here is that you have a deeply nested set of potentially independent and reusable functions. There are two approaches to this problem that come to mind:

#### Use a control flow library

Use something like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) series, parallel, etc. (which function depends on the nature of your code – are all of the `call_` functions independent?) That will clean up your code and make it more maintainable.

#### Use ajax

Another approach you can take is to quickly render the page without all of the `call_` functions and just make several ajax calls from the client to fill in the data. You could have routes which look like '/news/last', and '/news/hot', etc. This is nice because you can separate out all of the logic for each of these units into reusable URLs so you can mix and match them on any page.

Comment: Thank you david. I gonna read aboun async. Yes, the main concern in hard readable code.

No i don't want to use ajax because of search engines. I mean in this case i just want to build a page with "static" (without any ajax) content that can be easily read by google or etc.

Comment: it looks like i finally found a simple solution here http://www.screenr.com/elL
im not sure it's pretty correct solution but i try that too.
anyway, thanks again!